# How do I do a regression analysis with panel data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, analysis, panel-data

So I'm a noob at R and it's been more than a year since I've used R, and I've seem to forgot a lot... :(

I have a panel data that includes different countries with observations from 2005, 2010, and 2015 that looks like this:

```
   Location Year Health_Spending Total NCD Deaths_male
1      CAN 2005        3282.454                 101.4
2      CAN 2010        4225.189                 105.5
3      CAN 2015        4632.837                 109.2
4      ESP 2005        2126.553                 179.9
5      ESP 2010        2882.912                 180.6
6      ESP 2015        3175.457                 183.1
  Total NCD Deaths_female
1                   102.7
2                   107.3
3                   110.2
4                   170.4
5                   170.6
6                   180.8
```

I'm trying to run a regression analysis with Health_Spending as Y, and Total NCD Deaths_male & Total NCD Deaths_female as X1 and X2.

I've been looking up and it seems like plm package is used a lot to analyze panel data in R, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it.

Can a kind soul help me out and guide me on what I need to do?

(here's a dput version of my data just in case)

```
    structure(list(Location = c("CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "ESP", "ESP", 
"ESP", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "ISR", "ISR", "ISR", "JPN", "JPN", 
"JPN", "KOR", "KOR", "KOR", "MEX", "MEX", "MEX", "NLD", "NLD", 
"NLD", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "POL", "POL", "POL", "TUR", "TUR", 
"TUR", "USA", "USA", "USA"), Year = c(2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 
2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 
2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 
2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 
2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L), Health_Spending = c(3282.454, 
4225.189, 4632.837, 2126.553, 2882.912, 3175.457, 2331.136, 3040.114, 
4071.806, 1768.952, 2032.725, 2646.915, 2463.725, 3205.216, 4428.349, 
1183.438, 1895.699, 2481.587, 730.816, 911.351, 1037.424, 3454.707, 
4633.738, 5148.399, 3980.768, 5162.669, 6239.435, 806.974, 1352.424, 
1687.009, 582.888, 871.677, 1028.911, 6443.02, 7939.798, 9491.4
), `Total NCD Deaths_male` = c("101.4", "105.5", "109.2", "179.9", 
"180.6", "183.1", "245.8", "242.0", "249.0", "16.7", "16.8", 
"18.0", "460.3", "503.7", "543.2", "105.7", "110.2", "118.3", 
"194.7", "230.7", "257.5", "58.9", "58.6", "63.2", "17.4", "17.5", 
"17.1", "172.7", "175.1", "175.9", "185.3", "197.4", "211.8", 
"1024.9", "1061.6", "1159.5"), `Total NCD Deaths_female` = c("102.7", 
"107.3", "110.2", "170.4", "170.6", "180.8", "268.2", "259.0", 
"264.1", "17.5", "17.4", "18.7", "405.0", "458.9", "528.4", "92.9", 
"93.3", "102.2", "181.4", "214.2", "235.5", "62.1", "62.6", "67.7", 
"18.4", "18.8", "18.2", "163.1", "168.6", "174.6", "150.3", "162.6", 
"181.0", "1111.6", "1115.5", "1183.4")), .Names = c("Location", 
"Year", "Health_Spending", "Total NCD Deaths_male", "Total NCD Deaths_female"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Comment: try `plm(Health_Spending~Deaths_male+Deaths_female, df)` You'll need to rename the variables (I don't think the function likes the ticks in the variable names) and you'll want to convert your death columns to numeric

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you'd like to use a standard multiple regression approach. And you can easily do that with `lm(Health_Spending~Total.NCD.Deaths_male + Total.NCD.Deaths_female + Location, data = df)`. Just make sure that the the variables `Total NCD Deaths_male` and `Total NCD Deaths_female` are of ype `numeric`, and `Location` is of type `categorical`.

The following snippet will show you how to change the data types, build a model, and report model results.

---

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(structure(list(Location = c("CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "ESP", "ESP", 
                "ESP", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "ISR", "ISR", "ISR", "JPN", "JPN", 
                "JPN", "KOR", "KOR", "KOR", "MEX", "MEX", "MEX", "NLD", "NLD", 
                "NLD", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "POL", "POL", "POL", "TUR", "TUR", 
                "TUR", "USA", "USA", "USA"), Year = c(2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 
                2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 
                2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 
                2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 
                2010L, 2015L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L), Health_Spending = c(3282.454, 
                4225.189, 4632.837, 2126.553, 2882.912, 3175.457, 2331.136, 3040.114, 
                4071.806, 1768.952, 2032.725, 2646.915, 2463.725, 3205.216, 4428.349, 
                1183.438, 1895.699, 2481.587, 730.816, 911.351, 1037.424, 3454.707, 
                4633.738, 5148.399, 3980.768, 5162.669, 6239.435, 806.974, 1352.424, 
                1687.009, 582.888, 871.677, 1028.911, 6443.02, 7939.798, 9491.4
                ), `Total NCD Deaths_male` = c("101.4", "105.5", "109.2", "179.9", 
                "180.6", "183.1", "245.8", "242.0", "249.0", "16.7", "16.8", 
                "18.0", "460.3", "503.7", "543.2", "105.7", "110.2", "118.3", 
                "194.7", "230.7", "257.5", "58.9", "58.6", "63.2", "17.4", "17.5", 
                "17.1", "172.7", "175.1", "175.9", "185.3", "197.4", "211.8", 
                "1024.9", "1061.6", "1159.5"), `Total NCD Deaths_female` = c("102.7", 
                "107.3", "110.2", "170.4", "170.6", "180.8", "268.2", "259.0", 
                "264.1", "17.5", "17.4", "18.7", "405.0", "458.9", "528.4", "92.9", 
                "93.3", "102.2", "181.4", "214.2", "235.5", "62.1", "62.6", "67.7", 
                "18.4", "18.8", "18.2", "163.1", "168.6", "174.6", "150.3", "162.6", 
                "181.0", "1111.6", "1115.5", "1183.4")), .Names = c("Location", 
                "Year", "Health_Spending", "Total NCD Deaths_male", "Total NCD Deaths_female"
                ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L)))


# Data transformation
df$Health_Spending <- as.numeric(df$Health_Spending)
df$Location <- as.factor(df$Location)
df$Total.NCD.Deaths_male <- as.numeric(df$Total.NCD.Deaths_male)
df$Total.NCD.Deaths_female <- as.numeric(df$Total.NCD.Deaths_female)

# Model and model summary
m <- lm(Health_Spending~Total.NCD.Deaths_male + Total.NCD.Deaths_female + Location, data = df)
summary(m)
```

In the summary you'll find all Locations as explanatory factor variables except 'Canada'. This is because Canada automatically has been selected as a reference variable to which all other locations are being compared. In the model summary you can see that `Total.NCD.Deaths_female` is considered insignificant while `Total.NCD.Deaths_male` is considered weakly significant at the 10 percent level (indicated by the '.')

Some words of caution

---

You should always pay attention to the structure of your data before you build a model. If you decide to remove the `Location` variable in your model, you'll get very different results, perhaps even concluding that both variables `Total.NCD.Deaths_male` and `Total.NCD.Deaths_female` are highly significant:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Health_Spending ~ Total.NCD.Deaths_male + Total.NCD.Deaths_female, 
    data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2319.8 -1176.5    56.6   943.0  3535.2 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              2615.17     362.78   7.209 2.89e-08 ***
Total.NCD.Deaths_male     -36.39      11.83  -3.077  0.00418 ** 
Total.NCD.Deaths_female    39.08      11.34   3.447  0.00156 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1509 on 33 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5136,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4841 
F-statistic: 17.42 on 2 and 33 DF,  p-value: 6.849e-06
```

This will, however, be a wildly misleading conclusion because of the structure of your dataset:

[image]

As you can see, all Locations appear multiple times. The same thing goes for `Year`. And without subsetting the data, the simpler `model m <- lm(Health_Spending~Total.NCD.Deaths_male + Total.NCD.Deaths_female, data = df)` will not take that into account. Using `Location` as a factor variable will remedy that to some extent, but you should also consider including `Year` as an explanatory variable of either type `numeric` or `categorical`, or perhaps take the time element into account in some other way - perhaps by splitting the dataset into different periods.

I hope this is what you were looking for. Don't hesitate to let me know if not.